# Have large lists of DVDs with years of movies, cannot get the two separated as lists into dictionary format

Tags: regex, list, dictionary

Hello I am using a Python(3.8.2) for loop with this list of DVD's a family member has given me, all organized as:

```
A Walk Among the Tombstones (2014)
Blithe Spirit (2020)
Jeepers Creepers (2001)
The Place Beyond the Pines (2012)
```

etc....

Search code:

```
inp = input().lower().title()
if inp in movieTitle:
    print(inp+ " DVD is AVAILABLE")
else:
    print("THIS DVD IS NOT AVAILABLE")
```

Code to extract titles/years:

```
for lin in L:
    movieName = re.findall('(^.*)\s', lin)
    movieTitle.append(movieName)
    movieYr = re.findall('(\(....\))$', lin)
    movieYear.append(movieYr)
```

note: ('L' is the original list created from the string of the .txt file)

I am creating a search via user input to check for existing titles. I have been successful at retrieving just the titles of the DVD's using re.findall so that the user input easier matches the title (otherwise it will show as non existant without them entering the year in parentheses).

The ISSUE I am having is that once I extract just the titles, I now have a list in which I cannot add into a dictionary as a Key. The movie years I have extracted separately as well, and those I want to add as the Value to the key.

I have had many "unhashable type" list errors and have reviewed many posts regarding a similar situation. Where my situation doesn't seem to relate, is that my titles have spaces and multiple words for certain titles as well as many line items.

Please advise how I may approach this in another way; thanks and cheers~

Comment: What is the code you need to fix? Please add it to the question. Only keep the relevant information in the question. It is not clear what `Search code` does here.

Comment: Hello Wiktor. My problem was that I was getting "lists" returned from my re.findall which I was unable to create a dictionary with. What I was requesting was a possible alternate approach to extract my data from my movie list while being able to still create a dictionary with the extracted data. The gentlemen Andrej Kesely has read into my inquiry and advised the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `re.findall` will return a `list` so you cannot use that as a dictionary key. You can use `re.search` and the get correct search group. For example:

```py
import re

with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    L = f_in.readlines()


movies = {}
for lin in L:
    movieName = re.search(r"^([^(]+)", lin).group(1).strip()
    movieYr = re.search(r"\((\d+)\)$", lin).group(1)
    movies[movieName] = movieYr

inp = input("Search for movie: ").lower().title()

if inp in movies:
    print(inp + " DVD is AVAILABLE")
else:
    print("THIS DVD IS NOT AVAILABLE")
```

Prints:

```
Search for movie: Blithe Spirit
Blithe Spirit DVD is AVAILABLE
```

The `movies` dictionary is:

```py
{
    "A Walk Among the Tombstones": "2014",
    "Blithe Spirit": "2020",
    "Jeepers Creepers": "2001",
    "The Place Beyond the Pines": "2012",
}
```

Comment: Ah wow, thank you Andrej! I did not realize that by using re.search instead of findall that I would be able to avoid the results becoming Lists. Thank you for that. Also I enjoyed your  reworking of my re, I will keep the "r" in mind for raw strings next time. Great stuff.
If you are able to elaborate; what is the advantage of opening the text file via "with" "as" vs
just  x = open('text.txt'), then for line in x?

Comment: @ArtimusMaximus with `with` the file is automatically closed. It's generally good practice to clean-up the resources after they are used (`with` do it automatically)

Comment: @ Andrej Kesely Another gem of information, thank you Andrej, it looks like I have a new and preferred way of dealing with filles. My project is moving forward as well, thanks again!